# PostgreSQL "paging" jsp

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

some part of my code...

```
String url = ****
String user = ****
String pass = ****
String a = "***";


try{
                              Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                              conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,pass);

 String SQL = "select * from Atable where A ilike ?";
 pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
 pstmt.setString(1, "a");

 rs = pstmt.executeQuery();


 while(rs.next()){
 out.println("rs.getString()");
 }


}catch(Exception e){

 e.printStackTrace();
                          }finally{
                              try{
 if(rs != null) rs.close();
 if(pstmt != null) pstmt.close();
 if(conn != null) conn.close();
                              }catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
                              }
}
```

I want to apply paging on result set. 
I already know LIMIT function in postgresql but I can't apply for paging 
because I am beginner.

Comment: I do hope that code is not part of your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

`limit A` - defines size of page to `A`
`offset B` - moves start of the page by `B`

Please note that PG will execute your query, and then skip result according to `offset`. Fetching small page makes DB processing whole long result, which is slow.

## EDIT

Here is sample pagination, for MySQL, but idea is fully described:
http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jsp/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/

Key part looks like this:

```
    int page = 1;
    int recordsPerPage = 5;
    if(request.getParameter("page") != null)
        page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
    EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
    List<Employee> list = dao.viewAllEmployees((page-1)*recordsPerPage,
                             recordsPerPage);
    int noOfRecords = dao.getNoOfRecords();
    int noOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(noOfRecords * 1.0 / recordsPerPage);
    request.setAttribute("employeeList", list);
    request.setAttribute("noOfPages", noOfPages);
    request.setAttribute("currentPage", page);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("displayEmployee.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
```

So, when you visit page, without `page` parameter - `1` is taken. In other cases, passed parameter is taken. DAO is used, which is good idea, since you separate data operation from business logic description. In this example `dao.viewAllEmployees((page-1)*recordsPerPage, recordsPerPage)` - you pick up records for the page. Query should look like this:

```
select * from Atable where A ilike ?param offset ?firstRecord limit ?recordsPerPage
```

Technically that will work. But edit can change order or records in the table. So without `order by` clause you can see old records appears at the end... As @dsp_user described.

Comment: thank you for your help. For example, there are 57 results, i want to show the result in tens. how can i pass first result page to second result page and how can i stop the paging when number of result is less than 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

For paging to work, you must use an **ORDER BY** clause in your sql query, followed by a **LIMIT x OFFSET y** clause.

```
String SQL = "select * from Atable where A i like ? ORDER BY id  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20";
```

This query above will first sort records by id in ascending order, skip the first 20 records and return 10 records.